# Data consistency with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

What options are there to ensure that changes on documents in a MongoDB are not lost in case of a system that works as follows: some workers process (in parallel) Tasks that consist of some sequential steps:

- read a document from MongoDB (based on some criteria dependent of task type)
- perform some changes on the document (the changes are pretty complex and require queries to some other services so something like db.collection.findAndModify() would not work)
- write the document back to MongoDB

If we consider the CRUD terminology we would have for each Task RU operations. The problem will appear in the case RRUU (on the same document) since the second (last) update will overwrite the first (previous) one(s)

The question is how to ensure that document changes are not lost assuming two or more tasks concomitantly make changes on the same document ?

Comment: As per the docs, any single write operation on a single document is atomic. To make multiple operations are performed as a single unit you can use Transactions.

Comment: As I said in my post the workers process the tasks in parallel (different threads that may even run on different machines). As far as I know you cannot group these operation into a single transaction. In a standard relational DB like MySql it would be possible to put a RU unit into a transaction but as far as I know MongoDB doesn't not support something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that immediately comes to mind is versioning your documents.

Let each document have a field `version` with, say, integer values.

- Worker 1 reads a document and sees that its version is `5`.
- Worker 2 reads this same document.
- Worker 1 completes calculation of the new content for the document and performs a `findAndModify({id: document.id, version: 5}, { ...set document data here and increment the version...})`
- Worker 2 completes calculation of the new content for the document and attempts to run the same `findAndModify({id: document.id, version: 5}, { ...different content...})`
- Worker 2 fails to find the document for update, because `version` is no longer 5. It now can abort the write or re-read the document and retry.

Comment: I am doing exactly this for my "in Memory" storage implementation but I didn't consider that I could actually do the same with Mongo too :) ...